# How to set up a trigger that works at first day of every year?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to make trigger that works at Jan. 1st of every year, which will make a copy of spreadsheet and bring only the data from last month from original spreadsheet.

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger(myFunction)
.timebased()
.at(yyyy, 01, 01)
.create()
```

What method will make 'yyyy' to be changed automatically when the year changes to next year

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48089758/11581830) provides a workaround to accomplish this, since GAS does not allow yearly triggers. In essence, you have a monthly trigger on the 1st of the month that, through an if statement checks whether it is January, and if so, it runs your function.

Comment: Thanks for the solution!

Comment: No problem, happy to help!

Comment: Just one more question - Does trigger builder works properly if the script is embedded in spreadsheet?

Comment: It does!, alternatively you can create one through the dashboard (also monthly) and at the start of the script check if the "current" date is Jan 1st. But there shouldn't be a problem with using the trigger builder with the bounded script, it would work the same if you were building an `onEdit()` trigger, for example

Comment: You're right, I didn't have to create trigger builder in script. Maybe I was thinking bit complicated. Anyways, again, thanks for the solution.