# Trying to sort out Google Yearly Time-driven Trigger but failed

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-sheets-api

As the Google Apps Script doesn't support yearly triggers, I am trying to run a monthly trigger that runs on a certain date of every month, and if the month is matching my criteria, run the actual function. Here is the code written:

```
function createYearlyTrigger() {

const sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("mobile") //<- insert Sheet name
const subjectLine = "Message sent to be Yearly | {{Property}}"; // <-- Insert email draft subject line
sheet.getRange("AH2:AH").setValue("")
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("shouldTriggerRun")
  .timeBased().onMonthDay(17).atHour(19).create();
}

function shouldTriggerRun() {
  var date = new Date();
  if (date.getMonth() === 3) {
    incrementCell();
  }  
  sendEmails(subjectLine, sheet);
}
```

Now my target is to run the trigger on 17th day of April. I am also using the following trigger:

[image]

But it is not working properly.

Please let me know where I am doing wrong.

Comment: What exactly is not working? And how are you testing it? Just looking at the functions, `shouldTriggerRun()` should run in April as expected. However, `sheet`, `subjectLine` and `sheet.getRange("AH2:AH").setValue("")` should all be within `shouldTriggerRun()`. Also, I don't know if there would be any errors after that since we don't know how `incrementCell()` and `sendEmails()` work. For starters you should move the variables to the right function anyway.

Comment: Thanks for checking this, @Daniel. Re. incrementcell(), I have got this from the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48089619/how-to-create-a-yearly-time-driven-trigger?rq=1

I've updated the script a little bit as follows:

Comment: function createYearlyTrigger() {
  var date = new Date();
  date.setMonth(1); // Set the month to January
  date.setDate(20); // Set the day to the 1st of the month
  date.setHours(16); // Set the hours to 00:00:00
  date.setMinutes(0); // Set the minutes to 00
  date.setSeconds(0); // Set the seconds to 00

   var triggerDay = date.getTime();
  var recurrence = ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
    .timeBased()
    .atDate(date.getFullYear() + 1, date.getMonth(), date.getDate())
    .create();
}